# Improve the performance of this code

Tags: performance, matlab

Suppose I have a matrix called A:

```
3 0 3 3
0 0 4 0
```

And I have this function:

```
while(1)
  if all(A(:,i) == 0)
    i = i + 1;
  else
    i = i + 1
    break;
  end
end
```

How can I improve the performance of this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very easily:

```
i = sum(all(A==0,1),2)
```